# Selenium Issue causing Chrome to Crash

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Got some problems with getting my selenium script to run in a container. Basically Flask with an HTML client, screenshots passed to html client. Selenium task to load up the site and sign in etc -

## Create a global variable to store the WebDriver instance

```
driver = Nonedriver_lock = threading.Lock()def get_active_driver():global driverwith driver_lock:if driver is None or not driver.session_id:options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()options.add_argument('--headless')options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

```
    driver.maximize_window()  # Maximize the window first

    return driver
```

Build file -

```
# Use an official Python base image
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .

# Install additional dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unzip \
    chromium \
    chromium-driver \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Unzip templates.zip to /app
RUN unzip -o templates.zip -d /app

# Make port 8050 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8050

# Run present_tradingview.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "/app/Selenium.py"]
```

The Issue I have. Works fine on windows :

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneTypeTraceback (most recent call last):File "/app/selenium.py", line 151, in capture_screenshotdriver = get_active_driver()File "/app/selenium.py", line 134, in get_active_driverdriver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in initsuper().init(File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 61, in initsuper().init(command_executor=executor, options=options)File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in initself.start_session(capabilities)File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_sessionresponse = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in executeself.error_handler.check_response(response)File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_responseraise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

1. Tried a number of tricks to increase logging
2. Tried other images including the official Selenium image.
3. Tried the ubuntu image
4. Tried checking driver and chrome version and verifying it is correct/compatible
5. Tried boosting permissions

Open to ideas!

Fix -

```
# Use an official Python base image
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . .

# Install additional dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unzip \
    chromium \
    chromium-driver \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Unzip templates.zip to /app
RUN unzip -o templates.zip -d /app

# Unzip static.zip to /app
RUN unzip -o static.zip -d /app

# Make port 8050 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8050

# Run present_tradingview.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "/app/Scripty.py"]
```

Comment: Added Fix to my question. Thanks All!! Basically no change. Looks like it was a Build issue with the latest Chromium Driver